# Determining input for Overloaded Method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, overloading

I'm running into a bit of an issue with determining if the user input is an int or double.

Here's a sample:

```
public static int Square(int x)
{
    return x*x;
}

public static double Square(double x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

I need to figure out how to determine based on the Scanner if the input is a int or double for the above methods. However since this is my first programming class, I'm not allowed to use anything that hasn't been taught - which in this case, has been the basics.

Is there anyway of possibly taking the input as a String and checking to see if there is a '.' involved and then storing that into an int or double?

Lastly, I'm not asking for you to program it out, but rather help me think of a way of getting a solution. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Sounds like a fun class.

Answer (score 2):

The Scanner has a bunch of methods like `hasNextInt`, `hasNextDouble`, etc. which tell you whether the "next token read by the `Scanner` can be interpreted as a (whatever)".

Comment: The problem with using methods such has hasNextInt, etc. is that these are things that haven't been taught in class, and therefore, in the professor eyes they aren't allowed. I appreciate the help :) Is there any other type of solution to getting around this?

Comment: I really do hate that sort of nonsense in CS classes :) It would help if we knew exactly what you're allowed to use...

Comment: It's been a really basic CS class - we've learned how to create classes (constructors, successors, mutator, helper), loops (do-while, while, for, if, if-else, etc). We just barely begun to learn calling a method without having to create the object. (Hopefully that was stated correctly - basically calling Math.whatever()). (Perhaps I should ask if calling any class/method is free game at this point) The scanner class has just been limited to nextInt, nextDouble, next. I don't really know what else to list that would be of any use/guidance into helping me solve my problem above.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you've learned about [the `Scanner` object](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), I assume the methods of that class are available to you for your use. In this case, you can detect if an input is an integer, double, or just obtain an entire line. The methods you would most be interested here would be the `hasNextDouble()` method (returns a `boolean` indicating whether or not the current token in the `Scanner` is actually a `double` or not) and the `nextDouble()` method (if the next token in the `Scanner` is in fact a `double`, parse it from the `Scanner` as one). This is probably the best direction for determining input types from a file or standard input.

Another option is to use the wrapper classes static methods for converting values. These are generally named like `Integer.parseInt(str)` or `Double.parseDouble(str)` which will convert a given `String` object into the appropriate basic type. See the `Double` classes method [`pasrseDouble(String s)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) for more details. It could be used in this way:

```
String value = "123.45"
double convertedValue = 0.0;

try {
    convertedValue = Double.parseDouble(value);
} catch (NuberFormatException nfe) {
    System.err.println("Not a double");
}
```

This method is probably best used for values that exist within the application already and need to be verified (it would be overkill to construct a `Scanner` on one small `String` for this purpose).

Finally, yet another potential (but not very clean, straightforward, or probably correct technique) could be looking at the `String` object directly and trying to find if it contains a decimal point, or other indicators that it is in fact a `double`. You may be able to use [`indexOf(String substr)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) to determine if it appears in the `String` ever. I suspect this method has a lot of potential problems though (say for example, what if the `String` has multiple '.' characters?). I wouldn't suggest this route because it is error prone and hard to follow. It might be an option if that's what the constraints are, however.

So, IMHO, your options should go as follow:

1. Use the `Scanner` methods `hasNextDouble()` and `nextDouble()`
2. Use the wrapper class methods `Double.parseDouble(String s)`
3. Use `String` methods to try and identify the value (avoid this technique at all costs if either of the above options are available).

Answer (score 1):

Since you think you won't be allowed to use the Scanner methods there are a number of alternatives you try. You mentioned checking to see if a String contains a `.`. To do this you could use the contains method on String.

```
"Some words".contains("or") // evaluates to true
```

The problem with this approach is that there are many Strings that contain `.` but aren't floating point numbers. For examples, sentences, URLs and IP addresses. However, I doubt you're lecturer is trying to catch you out with and will probably just be giving you ints and doubles.

So instead you could try casting. Casting a double to an int results in the decimal portion of the number being discarded.

```
double doubleValue = 2.7;

int castedDoubleValue = (int) doubleValue; // evaluates to 2

double integerValue = 3.0;

int castedIntegerValue = (int) integerValue; // evaluates to 3
```

Hopefully, that should be enough to get you started on writing a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can be checked like this

```
            if(scanner.hasNextDouble()}
            {
               System.out.println("Is double");
            }


            if(scanner.hasNextDouble()}
            {
              System.out.println("Is double");
            }
```

Comment: Watch the typo on the condition - if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) is what you meant. Also, it's good to note that to check the next element, one must call next() or nextDouble(). So, between those two conditions, one should put a call to scanner.next().